# Значения инпута

Tags: jquery, javascript

Добрый день! 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как передать value инпута type="radio" в value инпута type="input" 
Нашел скрипт, но почему-то с типом радио не работает =/

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('14').addEventListener('input', function(e){
        document.getElementById('15').value = this.value;
    });
</script>
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

У вас один input с типом radio?
Если нет, то тогда надо получать их по классу или по name, а не по id.

Чтобы получить value значение, для input с типом radio надо найти, который отмечен.
В jquery это

```
$('input[name="radio"]:checked').val();
```

Если вы на чистом js хотите, то так:

```
 var radio = document.getElementsByName('radio');
  for (var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++) {
    if (radio[i].type === 'radio' && radio[i].checked) {
        rezultatRadio = radio[i].value;       
    }
  }
document.getElementById('15').value = rezultatRadio;
```

Comment: input'ов radio несколько, нужно, чтобы при выборе одного из этих radio inputo'ов подставлялось значение в input type="input".

Answer (score 0):

```
//попробуйте так
document.getElementById('14').onclick = function(){
        document.getElementById('15').value = this.value;
    }
```

Oops: я думал в js есть onchecked)))

Comment: Что за onchecked?

Comment: @eicto, ))) исправил.

Comment: Лучше change, если это checkbox или радио.

Comment: Значение в инпут попадает, но value не меняется =/

Comment: Видимо, у вас потому, что type="input", может, вы хотели type="hidden" или type="text"?

Comment: Надо именно в input.